# How to add libraries in a folder in a netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, memcached

I am a total java development noob. Thus I don't know how to work with projects in netbeans. Currently I am trying out memcached client for java.

Now I have created a project. I have downloaded a java memcached client named gwahlin memcached client (can be found here https://github.com/gwhalin/Memcached-Java-Client). Inside it's folder there's this folder structure `com/meetup/memcached` and within it are all the required java files. Now I have to import these files in netbeans.

I tried adding libraries from properties menu of the project. I added this folder, in the libraries within project explorer I can see the folder with the path of this memcached client added. Then when I write `import com.meetup.memcached.MemcachedClient;` I get error as that file is not found.

I know how to add jar and use it, but what to do in this case? I am totally clueless. Please help me here

Comment: can't you do project check out ? instead of copying files ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what ur talking about :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to project explorer. Exapnd your current project and simply paste the whole "com" folder in "src" folder. This import will work.

Comment: I used ur idea. I pasted the folder in src folder. That worked thanks. However, I have a question, my class where I wrote `import com.meetup.memcached.*`, means that this package should be at the same level as that of my class. But it is not so. My class file is in another folder named javamemcached which is contained within src folder. So I had to pased com folder outside javamemcached folder. How come?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [NetBeans IDE Java Quick Start Tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html)

There are two ways to import classes

1. External jars can be added by Project->Properties->Libraries
2. By adding classes directly in your project

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add the java files from gwhalin as a library? That won't work. Create a seperate Project for gwhalin probably best to use the Java Project with Existing sources for this. Then build your gwhalin project. When you have done that you can add it as a dependency to the libraries of your other project (right click the libraries node and choose Add Project).